# Time complexity of appending a list to a list

Tags: python

I understand the amortized complexity of appending an element to a list is O(1) but what is the time complexity of appending a list to a list?

For clarification:

Appending an element to a list

```
list_ = []  
for _ in range(0,n):  
    list_.append(1)
```

Appending a list to a list

```
list_ = []
list_.append([_ for _ in range(0,n)])
```

Comment: "appending" a list to a list is still O(1), you are just adding the reference to the list, "extending" a list of size m is going to cost you O(m), since it has to traverse the other list of size m to append every single element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing my comment again, "appending" a list to a list is still O(1), you are just adding the reference to the list, "extending" a list of size m is going to cost you O(m), since it has to traverse the other list of size m to append every single element.

```
seq = [1, 2, 3]
new_seq = [4, 5, 6]

# Appending is O(1)
seq.append(new_seq)
print(seq) # [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]

seq = [1, 2, 3]
new_seq = [4, 5, 6]

# Extending is O(m), m = len(new_seq)
seq.extend(new_seq)

print(seq) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


list_ = []
list_.append([_ for _ in range(0,n)])
```

You take O(n) time to create the list `[_ for _ in range(0,n)]` then O(1) time to add the reference of this list to your `list_`. O(n) in total for the line `list_.append([_ for _ in range(0,n)])`.

Answer (score 1):

[`list.append(item)` is `O(1)`, because lists are random-access. `list.extend(other_list)` is `O(k)`, where `k` is the size of the `other_list`, presumably because `memcpy` is also a linear-time operation.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Answer (score 1):

Since the implementation of `.extend` is really only fractionally slower than the in-place add, you can look at the source for `.extend` implementations for the answer, like here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

As you can see, there's some constant time overhead, setting up the resulting list with enough memory and the like. And then the iterator that the list is being extended with is being exhausted linearly, which means the time complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

If by "appending" you mean as `list.append(other_list)` the complexity is still O(1), the cost does not change depending on the element type.

While if you mean as in place concatenation `list.append(*other_list)` the complexity is O(n) where n are the elements of the second list.

The last case is the simple concatenation `list + other_list` where you are generating a third list, the complexity is O(m + n), m and n are the two lists sizes.